# Java doubly linked list looping

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, element, doubly-linked-list

My goal is to loop backwards through a list I have created and if an element is smaller than my chosen number `t` a node with the value of `t` will be inserted in front of the element that is  smaller. Also, if every element in the list is bigger than `t` a node with the value of `t` will be put at the start of the list. Example:

```java
DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);

list.addAtFirstSmaller(4);
System.out.println("Nodelist: " + list.toString());
```

And I should expect the outcome:
`[1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5]`
But instead I get:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]`

This is my code so far:

```java
public void addAtFirstSmaller(T t)
{
    ListNode<T> node = tail;
    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(t);
    while(node.previous != null)
    {
        int compared = node.previous.element.compareTo(t);
        node = node.previous;
        if(compared < 0)
        {
            ListNode<T> temp = node.next;
            node.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = temp;
            newNode.next.previous = newNode;
            node.previous = null;
            size++;
        }
        else if(compared > 0 && node.previous == null)
        {
            addFirst(t);
            size++;
        }
    }
}
```

To me it seems like everything is pushed to the right. Any idea on what to do?

Comment: `i should expect the outcome: [1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5]` Why is this the expected outcome? `t will be inserted in front of the element that is smaller.` If *t* is inserted in front of a smaller element, it should go after the 3, not before it.

Comment: Maybe i am misunderstanding my task, The task reads as: In this method you go through the elements in the list from behind (ie start from the end
of the list and progresses). As soon as an element in the list is less than t, t is added to
the list in front of that element. You can say that you go from the back of the list and find it
the first value in the list that is less than t ("first smaller") and adds t in front
the element (creates a node that you squeeze).

Comment: Yeah I think you misunderstood.  Your current output is correct.  I'd verify this with your instructor just in case.

Comment: Just sent him an email, i will mark this thread as solved if it is correct.

Comment: Before you mark the thread closed, please create an answer for it and then accept it. Unless somebody else puts an answer here.

Comment: It should be clarified what "in front of" means. It depends on which way you look at it. It would help if the ultimate purpose was clarified. Intuitively one would expect that the purpose is to maintain a sorted list... It makes no sense to insert a value in a sorted list at a position that would break this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already verified: the example output is correct as the idea is to maintain the list sorted. The misinterpretation was understandable, as *"in front of"* is somewhat ambiguous.

However, there are still a few issues with your code:

- Although the assignment `node.previous = null` will make the loop end once you have inserted the new node, this breaks a `previous` link that really should remain untouched. Only the head node should have `previous` equal to `null`, while in general `node` could have a predecessor, which must remain its predecessor.
- `newNode.previous` never receives a value. It should be set to `node`.
- When the value to insert is greater than the value in the tail node, the node will be inserted at the wrong spot -- there is never a scenario in your code where the new node will become the new tail, yet this is a possibility that should be foreseen.
- I would assume that `addFirst` would already increase `size`, so increasing it again after you call this function is wrong. This really should be the responsibility of `addFirst`.

Assuming that you have implemented `addLast`, the corrected code could be like this:

```
public void addAtFirstSmaller(T t) {
    ListNode<T> node = tail;
    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(t);
    while (node != null && node.element.compareTo(t) >= 0) {
        node = node.previous;
    }
    if (node == null) {
        addFirst(t);
    } else if (node == tail) {
        addLast(t);
    } else {
        ListNode<T> temp = node.next;
        node.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = temp;
        newNode.previous = node;
        temp.previous = newNode;
        size++;
    }
}
```

In case you don't have it yet, `addLast` could look like this:

```
public void addLast(T t) {
    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(t);
    tail.next = t;
    t.previous = tail;
    tail = t;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I alreade have the addLast method and now the codes works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just received an answer from my instructor, and it seems like my output is correct ([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] that is). I will mark this thread as closed as the code is working.

Comment: OK, your code still has an issue: it does not insert correctly a value that is larger than the tail value.